# C++ code in Android Studio: how to create a method stub by its declaration?

Tags: android-studio

I'm looking for a feature similar to "Implement method" in Eclipse, but can't find it anywhere (Google included). Surely, there must be a way to do that.

Comment: Using another JetBrains IDE (CLion) if I create a structure (or class, whatever) and write a member function declaration, I have a "Code" menu with the alternative "Generate definitions..." (default shortcut `Ctrl-Shift-D`) which brings up a list of all unimplemented member function, and then allows me to generate definitions (implementations) of those functions. All JetBrains IDEs (and Androis Studio is basically just a renamed JetBrains IDEA variant) are using the same base, and share many common things. Try looking around in the menus, context menus, possible lightbulbs?, etc.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: no lightbulbs appeared so far. Ctrl-Shift-D seems to have no effect, or I'm not placing the cursor where it needs to be for that to work.